# Quickly compare a string against a Collection in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, pattern-matching, edit-distance

I am trying to calculate edit distances of a string against a collection to find the closest match. My current problem is that the collection is very large (about 25000 items), so I had to narrow down the set to just strings of similar lengths but that still would only narrow it down to a few thousand strings and this still is very slow. Is there a datastructure that allows for a quick lookup of similar strings or is there another way I could address this problem?

Comment: How are you doing it right now? Can you show some code?

Comment: By similar I mean comparing words that are common spelling mistakes such as "exanple" and "example" or "weird" and "wierd".

Comment: Looks like you want an implementation of the levenstein distance: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6087281/similarity-score-levenshtein.

Comment: I am currently doing it the following way:
String currentString;  
List distanceList;
(for word: wordList){
  int distance = calculateDistance(currentString,word)
  distanceList.add(distance)
}

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sounds like a [BK-tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BK-tree) might be what you want.  Here's an article discussing them: http://blog.notdot.net/2007/4/Damn-Cool-Algorithms-Part-1-BK-Trees.  A [quick Google](https://www.google.com/search?btnG=1&pws=0&q=Burkhard+and+Keller+tree+java) yields some Java implementations.

Comment: Thanks I will look this up and let you know how it goes, thank you!

Comment: Yup that did it, needed a different implementation of the search but it was perfect! Thank you!!

Answer (score 6):

Levenshtein Automata allow for fast selection of a set of words from a large dictionary such that they are within the given Levenshtein distance from a given word.

See: Schulz K, Mihov S. (2002) [Fast String Correction with Levenshtein-Automata](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.16.652).

Answer (score 2):

If your criteria for 'similar' define a total ordering, you should be able to define a Comparator and use a TreeSet to find the closest matches (eg using the ceiling and floor methods).