# How many percentage one String is part of other String?

Tags: string, groovy, compare, spock

```
String a = 'string'
String b = 'This is a strin'
println b.containsSimilarity(a)
```

Is there a function like imaginary *containsSimilarity* in Groovy which to say the differences of strings,so
I want to search for **"string"** in
**"This is a strin"** and after comparison to say that **83%** of String "string" is found in **"This is a strin"**. 
Something like  assertions when using Spock

> assert "string"=="string"

result is:

> "string"=="strin"
>           |
>           false
>           1 difference (83% similarity)
>           strin(g)
>           strin(-)

How I can do this in Groovy? So not to compare two strings, but to find how big part of *String* **a** is containing in *String* **b**. If a is part of b ->true, else false and print similarity percentage and show where is the difference.

Comment: Isn't this related to Levenshtein distance on string? Maybe [this stackoverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6087281/similarity-score-levenshtein) has the answer

Comment: Not at all. My string b is very long and I want to search for some small part of it. So if my string b is English Alphabet, and String a is "w" after comparation I want result 100%, but with Levenshtein or Jaro-Walker it will be 0.03% or even less.

Comment: Here is one way https://blog.nishtahir.com/2015/09/19/fuzzy-string-matching-using-cosine-similarity/

More relevant would be looking at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/955110/similarity-string-comparison-in-java

Answer (score 0):

```
​def s1 = "string", s2 = "This is a strin"
def i = 0, j = 0, l1 = s1.size(), l2 = s2.size()

if (l1 >= l2) {
    large = s1
    small = s2
} else {
    large = s2
    small = s1
}

def percent = 100 / small.size()

def match(large, str) {
    if (large.indexOf(str) == -1) {
        return match(large, str.substring(0, str.size() - 1))
    }
    return str.size()
}

println(Math.round(match(large, small) * percent))  //83
​
```

Comment: Thanks, for the answer, but if we have s1= "very nice string", s2= "This is very strin" an the result will be 31%, but in fact there are 10 the same letters from 16 - approximately 63%. Because your algorithm cuts from behind. Only get 'very ' 5 leters If we have equal parts between something non equal problem occurs.

Answer (score 0):

I digged some Spock code, using 'similarity' as keyword and soon have found [EditDistance](https://github.com/spockframework/spock/blob/a26df7d34ad58c666619f25606a2437d0938d02d/spock-core/src/main/java/org/spockframework/runtime/condition/EditDistance.java) class. That class used in Spock for string distance calculation. It depends only on 
[EditPathOperation](https://github.com/spockframework/spock/blob/a26df7d34ad58c666619f25606a2437d0938d02d/spock-core/src/main/java/org/spockframework/runtime/condition/EditOperation.java), so it can be easily extracted.
If you want to pretty printed version, look at [EditPathRenderer](https://github.com/spockframework/spock/blob/a26df7d34ad58c666619f25606a2437d0938d02d/spock-core/src/main/java/org/spockframework/runtime/condition/EditPathRenderer.java). It depends on TextUtil.escape method, but it's extractable too.

But note, as Peter Niederwieser documented such classes calculates Levenshtein distance, and you noted, that it isn't exactly what you need. Author is at SO to, so maybe he can add something valuable to my answer.