# Strings partial matching

Tags: java, string, partial, matching

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Similarity String Comparison in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/955110/similarity-string-comparison-in-java)

**Hi all**

I am trying to find partial matching between two Strings  using **Java**, of course, there are lot of questions and answers on stackoverflow, however, non of these fulfill my requirment.
I have two strings (sentences), for example, "strong java programming" and "Strong  programing skill". 
Now I want to measure the degree of similarity  between these two sentences  like **25%** not just *partial matching* = **ture** or **false**.

**thanks**

Comment: What do you mean by a "25% match?"  How are you defining the percentage of a partial match?  And why are you assuming there is a Java API for it?

Comment: you need to provide more details.  What qualifies as a match? Is it just the overlap of words? is "strong programming" and "programming strong" a 100% match? Or are you doing some sort of weight analysis based on word order?

Comment: do you mean the percentage of consecutive characters they have in common?

Comment: by 25% match means these two sentences might be similar in %25 of their textual structure.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance

Comment: @solidfox, what is a textual structure?

Comment: user1329572 that correct and weight analysis , stemming  would help.

Comment: "textual structure"  I meant terms in side the sentences like 'program' 'Java'

Answer (score 6):

You can use string distance determination algorithms like [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) or [Jaro-Winkler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaro%E2%80%93Winkler_distance).

Answer (score 3):

Just use the String API and your own algorithms. Something like this:

```
public static double similarity(String a, String b) {
  double count = 0;
  String[] words = a.split();
  for(String word : words) {
    if(b.indexOf(word) != -1) {
      count++;
    }
  }
  return count / words.length;
}
```

**The catch** is that that's not quite right--you want to do a better job of looking at the words in B. I just wanted to give you a general idea of what methods and structure you might want to have. You also want to sanitize your input--make it all lower case, remove punctuation, who knows.

Comment: Do you mean `words.length`, not `a.length()`? And in either case, you need to check for divide-by-zero. Otherwise, you beat me to it (+1) ;-)

Comment: Good catch (I was even thinking arrays (I did have `length` instead of `length()`)...just flubbed it).

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at this library : [SimMetrics](http://sourceforge.net/projects/simmetrics/) .

> SimMetrics is a Similarity Metric Library, e.g. from edit distance's
>   (Levenshtein, Gotoh, Jaro etc) to other metrics, (e.g Soundex,
>   Chapman).

Comment: You can apply these metrics algorithms in this field(to compare similarity of strings), one of the common application is data mining ...