# Java search input

Tags: java, string, search, arraylist, substring

I need to create a JTextField search where users can enter input and matching entries in my arraylist of objects are returned in a JTextArea.

How can I return entries even if they have only entered part of say a movie title. For example, if the user enters only an "a" how can i return all entries within the ArrayList that begin with an a e.g abducted, aeon flux. Another example would be if the ArrayList contained a title "Harry Potter" how would i return this entry if the user only enters "harryp". It needs to work regardless of case.

Comment: I have been doing some research. Could I perhaps use Regex?

Answer (score 1):

You could work with `toUpperCase()` and `toLowerCase()` if you want it to be case unsensitive, and `startsWith()`.

If you really want "harryp" (without space) to match "Harry Potter", then you'll have to delete all the spaces in the entries before comparing the input.

If you provide some code, I can show you how this works.

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate the ArrayList and check for a similarity of your input and iterated item.
You can do it simple or more complex. The most simple would be make both strings lowercase and check for a substring.

If you want to have corrected misspelling you can use [Levenstein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) which tells you, how many characters you need to change in one string to get the other (and tolerate for example two misspells) - see Apache commons function [getLevenshteinDistance()](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang//apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#getLevenshteinDistance%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29).

For more insight see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/955110/similarity-string-comparison-in-java).