# Compare String of patterns

Tags: java

I have one string that contains **String s1="1 2 7 8"**
 now suppose I have two string **String s2="1 7 8"** and **String s3="1 2 8"**

so by comparing that two string to my first one it should return **true**.

But when I do `s1.contanis(s2)` it returns false.

Is there any other easy way to compare these type of patterns, without split each one and comparing one by one?

Comment: it's [similar_text](http://php.net/similar_text) in php [ [check this out](http://ideone.com/A8DWrI) ]... same question [here as well](http://stackoverflow.com/a/955122/1273830).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will do the job of checking if `s1` contains all the elements from `s2` (separated by a space):

```
Arrays.asList(s1.split(" ")).containsAll(Arrays.asList(s2.split(" ")));
```

Complete code:

```
public class StringContainsNumbers {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String s1 = "1 2 7 8";
        final String s2 = "1 7 8";
        final String s3 = "1 2 8";

        System.out.println(stringContainsNumbers(s1, s2));
        System.out.println(stringContainsNumbers(s1, s3));
    }

    private static boolean stringContainsNumbers(String s1, String s2) {
        return Arrays.asList(s1.split(" ")).containsAll(Arrays.asList(s2.split(" ")));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

s1 definitely does not contain s2.

what are you trying to do ? If you need to compare actual values, split and convert to integers

Comment: he understands that it returns false. the question here is how to do that. that to he wants to know if there is any library that supports this. He knows that it can be done through iterating the string.

Answer (score 1):

Contains checks for the whole `"1 7 8"` as string in `"1 2 7 8"`So it returns false.

You should use StringTokenizer Method.

Answer (score 0):

Because when you use s1.contains(s2), it does not compare single letters in the string but the entire string. 
For example, if the value of s1 is "2 1 7 8" then s1.contains(s2) will return true.

Answer (score 0):

you can do google search "Java - String matches() Method" You are going to find many links. One of them is:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_matches.htm

Answer (score 0):

Use following code:

```
public class Main {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    String one="1 7 8";
    String two= "1 2 8";
    List<String> fistList= Arrays.asList(one.split(" "));
    List<String> secondList= Arrays.asList(two.split(" "));
    boolean isContainAll=fistList.containsAll(secondList);
    System.out.println(isContainAll);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `contains` method on `String` only returns true if s1 completely contains s2. In other words

```
 String s1 = "hello world";
 s1.contains( "llo" );
```

Would return true but

```
 s1.contains( "ll w" );
```

would return false.

You'll need to tokenize both s1 and s2 and then check that the s1 elements contain all the s2 elements.