# How to know the percentage of equality of two texts or Strings in Java?

Tags: java, algorithm

Is there any method to know the percentage of equality of two texts or Strings in Java?

An algorithm of how to implement such a method would be satisfactory, or just a light.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because lack of effort from the OP

Comment: Yes, there are several.

Comment: @Cold [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/955110/similarity-string-comparison-in-java) might help you.

Comment: @RuchiraGayanRanaweera I believe maybe you are wrong because I have an idea, but it seems to be inefficient. So I questioned the possibility of some method already exists

Comment: @Cold yes. There is no such method.

Comment: what is a text is it single word? sentence or whole document? have a look here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:String_similarity_measures

Comment: When i mean Text i refer to an document or more that on String (String represents only a word) @user902383

Comment: you could try to go with cosine similarity

Answer (score 1):

Look at Levenshtein distance: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance

For Java implementation from Apache commons Refer :

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#getLevenshteinDistance(java.lang.CharSequence,java.lang.CharSequence)

Comment: Thanks @Ezequiel. Do you know what's the implemented method on `StringUtils`? I can't find it.

Comment: http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.3/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.java#StringUtils.getLevenshteinDistance%28java.lang.String%2Cjava.lang.String%29