# How would I consider two strings equal if they somewhat match

Tags: java, string, compare, string-comparison

Got a puzzle for someone to help me with. I want to compare two strings and pass them as equal if they match each other at a set percentage.

Here's what I', getting at...

```
if(string1.equals(string2,90)){
    System.out.print("Equal");
}
```

Where 90 is the variable that says the two strings need to match each other at least %90. And to make things more difficult, the two strings I am testing have variable numbers that show up within the string.

So an example is 
String1 = Hello World
String2 = Hello 2 World

The method would consider these two strings equal.

One way I thought this would be possible is somehow take both strings and delete all characters that don't have a pair on the other string and based on the number of characters thrown out, ratio-ed to the total you started with, pass or fail the test.

This way even Hello Dlr2ow2 would be considered a match to Hello World where it would throw out the "2's" and match each char left.

This seems like something that would be really cool to make, I just need some help on it.

Comment: I would suggest having a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance and then searching for one of the many Java examples for it.

Comment: Have you looked into using [Hamming distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance)?

Comment: Wonderful! Thanks, this should get the job done.

Comment: Would this kind of code work on jumbled up words such as Hello World compared to Dlrow Olleh?

Comment: What is "this kind of code" ?

Comment: The wiki link posted has some java code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to find similarity between two string.

Levenshtein distance method is available in org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.

A good reference - [Similarity String Comparison in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/955110/similarity-string-comparison-in-java)

Comment: Thanks! I got it working from the second response on that link.

Answer (score 0):

ANSWERED: I used this example to get my code working.

```
public class StringSimilarity {

  /**
   * Calculates the similarity (a number within 0 and 1) between two strings.
   */
  public static double similarity(String s1, String s2) {
    String longer = s1, shorter = s2;
    if (s1.length() < s2.length()) { // longer should always have greater length
      longer = s2; shorter = s1;
    }
    int longerLength = longer.length();
    if (longerLength == 0) { return 1.0; /* both strings are zero length */ }
    /* // If you have StringUtils, you can use it to calculate the edit distance:
    return (longerLength - StringUtils.getLevenshteinDistance(longer, shorter)) /
                               (double) longerLength; */
    return (longerLength - editDistance(longer, shorter)) / (double) longerLength;

  }

  // Example implementation of the Levenshtein Edit Distance
  // See http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance#Java
  public static int editDistance(String s1, String s2) {
    s1 = s1.toLowerCase();
    s2 = s2.toLowerCase();

    int[] costs = new int[s2.length() + 1];
    for (int i = 0; i <= s1.length(); i++) {
      int lastValue = i;
      for (int j = 0; j <= s2.length(); j++) {
        if (i == 0)
          costs[j] = j;
        else {
          if (j > 0) {
            int newValue = costs[j - 1];
            if (s1.charAt(i - 1) != s2.charAt(j - 1))
              newValue = Math.min(Math.min(newValue, lastValue),
                  costs[j]) + 1;
            costs[j - 1] = lastValue;
            lastValue = newValue;
          }
        }
      }
      if (i > 0)
        costs[s2.length()] = lastValue;
    }
    return costs[s2.length()];
  }

  public static void printSimilarity(String s, String t) {
    System.out.println(String.format(
      "%.3f is the similarity between \"%s\" and \"%s\"", similarity(s, t), s, t));
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    printSimilarity("", "");
    printSimilarity("1234567890", "1");
    printSimilarity("1234567890", "123");
    printSimilarity("1234567890", "1234567");
    printSimilarity("1234567890", "1234567890");
    printSimilarity("1234567890", "1234567980");
    printSimilarity("47/2010", "472010");
    printSimilarity("47/2010", "472011");
    printSimilarity("47/2010", "AB.CDEF");
    printSimilarity("47/2010", "4B.CDEFG");
    printSimilarity("47/2010", "AB.CDEFG");
    printSimilarity("The quick fox jumped", "The fox jumped");
    printSimilarity("The quick fox jumped", "The fox");
    printSimilarity("kitten", "sitting");
  }

}
```